# Alter single value in json string in text field

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have a table with one column of type text which contains a json string. I would like to do a query where I select a bunch of rows (around 50) and for these rows update a single value in the json that is saved in the text field. So lets say it currently looks like this

```json
{"amount":"45","level":1}
```

I want to update the amount value for every one of these rows, to for example "level" * 5.

I can't figure out a way to do this with one query since it does not seem possible to alter a single value for a text type field like this. Or am I missing something? Otherwise i will just have to alter it manually for every single row I need to change which would be a pain.

Comment: First see if you can cast the text to jsonb thusly:  `select mycol::jsonb from mytable`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to first cast the value to a proper `jsonb` value, then you can manipulate it using [JSON functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html).

```
update the_table
   set the_column = jsonb_set(the_column::jsonb, '{level}', to_jsonb((the_column::jsonb ->> 'level')::int * 5))::text
where ....
```

The expression `(the_column::jsonb ->> 'level')::int * 5` extracts the current value of `level` converts it into an integer and multiplies it with 5. The `to_jsonb()` around it is necessary because `jsonb_set()` requires a jsonb value as the last parameter

The `'{level}'` parameter tells `jsonb_set()` to put the new value (see above) into the (top level) key `level`

And finally the whole jsonb value is converted back to a `text` value.

---

If you really store JSON in that column, you should think about converting that column to the `jsonb` data type to avoid all that casting back and forth.

Or maybe think about a properly normalized model where this would be as simple as `set level = level * 5`